# PyCharm 2021.1.3 Community edition не визуализирует

Tags: python, pycharm, matplotlib

приведенный ниже код не производит никакой графики. Вижу сообщение: Process finished with exit code 0. Прошу помочь. Гуглил решения - не помогли.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def main():
    x_coords = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    y_coords = [0, 3, 1, 5, 2]
    plt.plot(x_coords, y_coords)
    plt.show()
main()
```

Comment: А импорт зачем отрезали? Мало ли что у вас в `plt`

Comment: добавил импорт, не разобрался с синтаксисом форума. Вопрос открыт.